# Which part of this Shakespearean sentence translates to: "Thank you"?

Tags: meaning, translation

This is a quote from The Tempest by Stephano:

> Be you quiet, monster.—Mistress line, is not this my
>   jerkin? Now is the jerkin under the line.

And it is translated (according to this [source](https://www.litcharts.com/shakescleare/shakespeare-translations/the-tempest/act-4-scene-1)) into:

> Be quiet, monster. Madame clothesline, isn't this my jacket? Thank you kindly. Now the jacket is under the line.

What is in the original text that translates to anything like expressing thanks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess is that [the source] is incorrect. I don't believe that any part of the original statement relates to the sentence "Thank you kindly"... It may be that the source is getting the sense of implied gratitude, but I see no reason why this should be.

Having read through a few more lines, I can see that [the source] has inferred more than just this line. For example:

> Hark, they roar.

Translates to:

> Listen, they’re roaring in pain.

No where does it explicitly state that they are roaring in pain, but [the source] has assumed that, that is the case.